# Unable to use states with ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, states

Let's consider this code snippet:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    /**/
    states: State {}
    /**/
}
```

When running the application, I get

```
Cannot assign to non-existent property "states"
```

When using

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    /**/
    Item { states: State {} }
    /**/
}
```

There is no error. Why can't I use `states` inside an `ApplicationWindow`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just realized that `ApplicationWindow` inherits `Window` inherits `QQuickWindow`. Only types which inherit from `Item` have the `states` property.

The workaround is to use `StateGroup`.

Feel free to add a better solution ;)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Unfortunately, doing this will break states support in Qt Designer; it doesn't recognise the `StateGroup`.

Also, noting that `ApplicationWindow` is the default root element in Qt Quick projects created using the New Project assistant, and official Qt tutorials suggest using root element states to build the interface (using Qt Designer), this is a confusion that many users will be bumping up against.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to code States within an QML ApplicationWindow using Qt v5.11, with two caveats. One was that the Qt Creator v4.6.1 editor flagged SignalTransition with a warning indicating a State cannot have a child item. Despite that warning, the code from the example at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html#a-simple-state-machine builds and runs correctly. The second caveat was that the Qt Creator editor ignored the major.minor version of import QtQml.StateMachine. Any numbers I typed in instead of 1.11 were accepted:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
    ...
```